# Why is FileNotFoundException popping up?

Tags: java, java-io, file-writing

I am trying to print Ben, Adam, John and Smith into a txt file with the names on separate lines. I am partly successful, however I keep getting FileNotFoundException at the end after the code runs. Why is that?

"Ben Adam John Smith" passes through `String names`

File Writing code:

```
public String writeYourName(String names) throws Exception {
    PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("names.txt")));
        for(int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
            output.write(names);
        }
        output.close();

    Scanner scan1 = new Scanner(new File("names.txt"));
        while(scan1.hasNext()) {
            if(scan1.hasNext()) {
                System.out.println(scan1.next());
            }
        }
        return names;
   }
```

Test file for FileWriting:

```
FileWriting fileWriting = new FileWriting();
FileReading fileReading = new FileReading();
fileWriting.writeYourName("Ben Adam John Smith");
System.out.println(fileReading.readName1(fileWriting.writeYourName("Fred")));
```

Code that the error points to:

```
public class FileReading {

public String readName1(String nameFile) throws Exception {
    -> Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File(nameFile)); <-
    String name = scan.next();
    String nextLine = "";
    while(scan.hasNextLine()) {
        nextLine = scan.nextLine();
    }
    return name + " " + nextLine;
}
```

Test file for FileReading:

```
System.out.println(fileInput.readName1("namefile.txt"));
```

Comment: Code works fine here. Although it's not exactly ideal. Are you certain the exception comes from **this** code? Can you post a complete MVCE?

Comment: At the end of the run, check that the file `names.txt` exists.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I read through the error carefully this time. Indeed you are right! 

But the error just points to code that looks like this : `Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File(nameFile));`

Comment: Then `nameFile` does not exist. Again, without a reproducible example of your problem there is nothing more to say.

Comment: `while(scan1.hasNext()) {
            if(scan1.hasNext()) {` is strange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to read a file where the filename consists of a name or names here:

```
fileReading.readName1(fileWriting.writeYourName("Fred"))
```

as `writeYourName` doesn't return a file name but a string of names of persons (or in this case, one name, of one person: Fred):

```
return names;
```